# function-like behavior without any callstack use

Tags: c, include, callstack, rtos, context-switch

I am working with a small cooperative OS (Salvo), in C, for an embedded target (MSP430).

I have to implement a command handler with a large number of non-reusable implementation codes. Those codes may include context switches, using the OS. During a context switch, the callstack is **NOT** saved, so I must remain at the same stack level. I am doing things this way, by including c files:

```c
TaskA()
{
    while(1)
    {
         command_code = OS_WaitMsgQ()

         switch(command_code)
             case 0x01:
             {
                 #include CSC0x01_Name_of_the_command.c
             }
             case 0x02:
             {
                 #include CSC0x02_Name_of_the_command.c
                     //OSContextSwitch()?
             }
             //100+ cases like this...
    }
}
```

This is working right now, but with this approach I loose most of the feature of my IDE when writing command specific codes, and I don't know if it will be manageable when the code will grow.

Is there a better solution?

Also, those command specific codes may use chunks of code that are reusable but that also contain context switches.

Is there something better than:

- copy and past?
- an involved and perilous multi-line macro?
- saving and restoring the stack using assembly for those common functions?

Or, which one is the lesser evil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write each of your commands as `inline` functions and call them as regular functions. This is a much nicer approach than what you've done, it just leaves it up to the compiler to generate the right code for you. A mess of `#include` like that will be in no way maintainable.

Comment: It could be a good solution, but my compiler may not agree: [link](http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/t/245902.aspx): The "inline" keyword does not force inlining. [...] f you really really want to force inlining, use the FUNC_ALWAYS_INLINE pragma.  It really does mean "always," so be careful:  extensive use could cause the compiler to run out of memory and crash.

Comment: After reflection, the exact same thing append with the includes. Thanks for your answer. Any insights on the second part?

Comment: Do what they said, and use the `FUNC_ALWAYS_INLINE` pragma. And be careful. :)